# React JSX const all words inside are orange

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I'm just wondering how come all of the text inside is orange (code shown here it is working but in my IDE Visual Studio it is not showing the colors)?

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const TopLayerContainer = styled.div`
    background-color: #1756dd81;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
`;

const WebLogo = styled.h1`
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 700;
`;

const Slogan = styled.h4`
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 1em;
    color: #fff
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;  
`;


export function topLayer() {
    return <TopLayerContainer>
        <WebLogo>This is Space</WebLogo>
        <Slogan>Theres no flat earth here</Slogan>
    </TopLayerContainer>
}
```

[image]

Comment: What you've posted here was _not_ the same. Now that I've fixed that, you can see it's the same - inside backticks it's a _string_.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue when I new to `styled-components`

Use this verified and popular plugin named `vscode-styled-components` in vs-code that not only help you solve linting issues but also provides auto-complete feature

[image]